# SQLITE SUM and LIMIT don't seem to work together

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm trying to retrieve the sum of a column from SQLITE. I am able to successfully get it.
But when I try to retrieve just the sum of 10 rows, it returns the sum of the entire column again. The query seems to be correct though.

```
public String getUnitsForWeek(Context context) throws IOException {
    DataBaseHelper dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context);

    String query = "SELECT sum(UNITS) FROM SERVICE_TABLE order by id DESC limit 7";
    return String.valueOf(dbHelper.getString(query));

}
```

The dbHelper.getString method is:

```
public int getString(String query) {
    String mypath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    SQLiteDatabase database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mypath, null, 
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    Cursor cursor = null;

    int i;

    cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);


    cursor.moveToFirst();
    i= cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(0)));
    return i;

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`SUM` is an aggregate function that combines data from many rows into one. Since there is only one result row, `LIMIT` and `ORDER BY` are meaningless.

To sum `UNITS` on the 7 rows with highest `ID`, you can use a subselect:

```
SELECT SUM(UNITS) FROM (SELECT UNITS FROM SERVICE_TABLE ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 7);
```

Answer (score 3):

Can't you do a subelect?

```
SELECT sum(UNITS) FROM (SELECT UNITS FROM SERVICE_TABLE order by id DESC limit 7) s
```

Comment: +1 thank you! i guess this is the same as what laalto has said.